# Magento 2 Helpers and best way to use helper method in phtml

Tags: magento2

There seems to be a couple of ways that you can load a helper to be used inside of a phtml file. However, I don't quite understand the advantages and disadvantages of the ways.

1. It seems the preferred Magento 2 way is to create a custom block and in the construct load the helper...

```
namespace Company\Module\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Company\Module\Helper\Data;


class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    private $_helper;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $helper)
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {

        return $this->_helper->isUserLoggedIn();
    }

}
```

And then use in phtml like this:

```
$block->isLoggedIn()
```

2. Another way, which seems to be discouraged(but works), is to load a helper via the phtml:

```
$helper = $this->helper('Company\Module\Helper\Data');
$helper->isLoggedIn();
```

- Why is this discouraged?

And finally...

3. Would it be considered bad practice if I make my helper `public` in the block that way I don't need to proxy the methods?

```
namespace Company\Module\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Company\Module\Helper\Data;


class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public $helper;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

And then use in the phtml as needed:

```
$block->helper->isLoggedIn()
```

Love to hear thoughts between these 3 ways to use a helper in phtml. I prefer to use Approach #2 because then I don't need to create custom blocks just to use a helper in a phtml file. However, if this is going to cause major slow down or issues I will avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

There is another approach to extend functionality of Magento 2 blocks. It's called **View Models**.

You can find docs here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

Note: View models are available in Magento 2.2 onwards.

### Simple example

Layout XML file `checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default">
<arguments>
    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">OrangeCompany\Catalog\ViewModel\MyNewViewModel</argument>
</arguments>
```

View model itself:

```
namespace OrangeCompany\Catalog\ViewModel;

class MyNewViewModel implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
      return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

And your phtml file:

```
<?php

/** @var $viewModel \OrangeCompany\Catalog\ViewModel\MyNewViewModel */

$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();

?>
<h1><?= $block->escapeHtml($viewModel->getTitle()); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for this example and the link to the documentation. Magento is stating this is the preferred way to use a helper with a template file.